# How-many-different-adjacency-matrix-with-N-vertices-and-E-edges-have?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

i'm studing graphs in algorithm and complexity and was perplexed in front of the following questions. I hope I get clear explanation for it...

> How-many-different-adjacency-matrix-with-N-vertices-and-E-edges-have?

I found out that the answer is n! on this website:
[source](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/21-127/lectures/graphs_2_print.pdf)

The link simply says that the number of possible matrix is equal to number of permutations of n elements.

But I don't know how to get this answer.

Comment: I don't see where the note you linked above says any thing like that.  A count of adjacency matrices for graphs with $N$ vertices and $E$ edges will depend on both $N$ and $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't believe everything you read online, or at least, you should take it with a grain of salt. Basically the author is saying that any permutation of vertices will give an isomorphic graph, if you consider the vertices to be ordered. The total number of permutations of $n$ vertices is $n!$. However this is not to say that the number of DISTINCT isomorphic graphs is always $n!$ if you have $n$ vertices. Consider for example the graph with no edges, or the graph with all edges. These have no other distinct isomorphic graphs, other than themselves, so the number of isomorphic graphs for these is simply 1, regardless of the number of vertices $n$.

Comment: Shouldnt **maximum possible number of adjacency matrices for $n$ node graph** be $(n!)^2$ for both undirected and directed graphs? We can permute rows of adjacency matrix in n! ways. Similarly we can permute columns of adjacency matrix in n!. For both directed and undirected graphs, permuting any one or both of rows and columns will give new adjacency matrix. So shouldnt it be $(n!)^2$?

Comment: @anir if you permute just the rows without applying the same permutation to the columns, you might not have an adjacency matrix anymore. (Consider that the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph must be symmetric, but permuting rows without permuting columns can break symmetry.)

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted Answer above explains what interpretation might be placed on the expression $n!$, i.e. counting the number of *labellings* of vertices in a graph $G$ that has $n$ vertices.  While such a labelling is required to get an adjacency matrix that represents a (simple) graph, it cannot account for the number of edges that we want such a graph to have.  Moreover two different labellings may or may not lead to the same adjacency matrix for $G$.

If a graph $G$ has $n$ vertices and $e$ edges, the possible adjacency matrices, without restriction as to which labelling is chosen, are given by choosing $e$ of the possible $\binom{n}{2}$ entries below the diagonal of the $n\times n$ matrix (setting these to $1$ and the rest of the entries, including the diagonal, to zero).

The same count, $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{e}$, is given by choosing an $e$-subset of the $\binom{n}{2}$ edges in the complete graph $K_n$ on $n$ vertices.